# What is a good IDE to edit javascript

Tags: javascript, ide

I am a new bie to Javascript.
I need to start learning angular js.
I know IDE WebStorm, Sublime, Brackets.
What is good IDE for javascript? And how can I test my javascript easily.

Comment: If you tried three IDE's, use the one that works best for you. And test your JS in something like JSBin or on your own site. It is absolutely important to know your browser's developer tools (and that of the other big browsers: Firefox, IE, Chrome, and Safari if you are on a Mac).

Comment: Primarily opinion-based. Flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've tried out several editors already - which is great. I highly recommend you check out the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor which is available on Mac, Windows and Linux for free.

Some features Atom can do without you having to leave the editor & open another application:

- run your code & have the output displayed in the editor
- open multiple terminal sessions
- run various testing suites from within the editor

Here is a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFAzqvYoHJs) I made a few weeks ago covering more than a dozen of plugins I use for javascript development, including the three plugins I mentioned above.

There are a variety of great plugins for Atom. You can find more packages on their [website](https://atom.io/packages).

I also made a [comprehensive list](http://cliffordfajardo.com/2016/atom-editor-review/) of Atom editor plugins to install.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the "run your code & have the output displayed in the editor" feature please? I've never heard about it.

Comment: There is a package called[ Atom Runner ](https://atom.io/packages/atom-runner) that I use to see the output of function calls etc. The video link above shows me running it on a ruby, python and javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Webstorm is best, especially with angular